# What is the type this string? a:1:{s:2:"en";}

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
a:1:{s:2:"en";s:39:"Sample Text";}
```

Shortly my question, do you have an idea about the above format?

I want to store long site settings following array like above format like JSON.

```
$settings = array(
            'slug' => 'test',
            'title' => 'John Doe',
            'description' => 'A Yes or No option for the module',
            '`default`' => '1',
            '`value`' => '1',
            'type' => 'select',
            '`options`' => '1=Yes|0=No',
            'is_required' => 1,
            'is_gui' => 1,
            'module' => 'johndoe'
        );
```

It look likes JSON but probably it's not.

I have not any idea about this format reading and creating.

In fact which PHP and MySQL Datatype to use for storing long params with best performance?

Comment: Please have *some* idea about what you want before you start asking us to do your work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datatype you're showing us here is a serialized variable in PHP.

To serialize or unserialize it, just use these two methods :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

To store it in MySQL, depends on the size of the serialized data. VARCHAR, TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT or BIGTEXT are available.

Comment: ^ very little in it, JSON is human readable though, and cross platform

Comment: No idea. In both cases you'll need to serialize them to store them in a database.
Try using NoSQL databases, maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`.

Better yet here are some perfomance numbers. But note I believe he was using some indexing his tests.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105964

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it that is a serialized PHP string.

You can use any normal text field to store its data. Which field type you use depends on how long you expect the data to be.

If it's just a blog post title you could use 'varchar'. With 'varchar' you're limited to 255 characters, if you need to store lots of text then you might be better off using  a 'text' field.